# React custom hook to fetch data returns previous searched value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

The console.log in 'resolveOptions' will always display the server results from previous search but the console.log in useEffect will display the correct current server results. What changes are needed to make sure that 'resolveOptions' will have the correct results?

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
const { data, getData } = usePromise();

const usePromise = () => {
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>();
    const dataRef = useRef<string[]>();

    const  { results } = useHookToFetchDataFromServer({ filter: { field: searchValue} });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (results) {
            const items = results.items.map(item => item.label);
            dataRef.current = items;
            console.log(dataRef.current); // logs the correct value received from the server based on the 'search string'
        }
    }, [results]);

    const getData = (searchVal: string) => {
        setSearchValue(searchVal);
    };

    return {
        data: new Promise<string[]>(resolve => resolve(dataRef.current)),
        getData
    };
}

const resolveOptions = (search: string): Promise<string[]> => {
    getData(search);
    data.then(res => console.log(res)); // will log the previous results from the server (e.g. If I search for A, then for B, instead of showing results for B it will show results for A) 

    return prom;
}

return (<MyChildComponent optionsResolver={resolveOptions}/>);
```

}

Comment: First thing is to not define hooks inside your components.

Comment: Second thing, looks like you don't actually need the ref and the effect. You can just try assigning the mapped array directly to a variable during render and then remove the effect.